# expanding 2 digit numeric range with alphabet

Tags: java, alphanumeric

I have string representing unigue value with 2 digit numeric prefix + fixed code + own value (operator id) like this

**01**DD001,**01**DD002, ..,**99**DD999

The string has given length and the length of DD part canot be changed . When I designed this unigue identificator I was told then the prefix would never exceed 99. Now we have to expand the prefix as the operator id exceeded the 99. So If I want to expand the range I have to change the decimal prefix to two digit hexadecimal which gives me range  0-256.
Other posible solution  is to threat it as string and use the whole alphabet for expanding the posible number of unique identificators as this

```
100 = A0 , 
111 = B1 ,
129 = C9...
```

So the question is is there some library which would use the second aproach (or simmilar)

Comment: Oh, the good old "I was told *<insert noun>* would never exceed *<insert quantity>*.". And guess what, it exceeded. You should prepare for the worst, I would use the entire alphabet, later you might have to add another digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BigInteger`. It has a convenient [toString(int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29) which you can use with a radix up to [Character.MAX_RADIX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX) which is generally at `36` giving you a maximum value of `ZZ` = `1295`.

Comment: @hege_hegedus - If you discard all numbers with only `0-9` in you only lose `99`, it still extends your range by `1000+`. I wll try to think up a better way though.

Comment: I think it is realy good sollution. I have to preserve allredy generated values  so I have to handle number smaller then 100 in the old way and with this solution last colliding value is 81. I can use this sollution. Thanks . Such nice function in base api.

Comment: Keep in mind that parsing "99" with BigInteger using some big radix will not give you 99 as integer

Answer (score 0):

You could always invent your own numbering system. Here's an example which is fairly well formed and reversible but only gives you a range of `0 - 1036` if you are limited to only uppercase.

```
/**
 * Number system where 0-99 appear as 0-99 but beyond that we can use A-Z.
 *
 * @param n - The number to convert.
 * @return - It's representation in this strange form.
 */
public static String strangeNumber(int n) {
    if (n < 100) {
        // 0 - 99 - The old way.
        String s = "00" + n;
        return s.substring(s.length() - 2);
    } else {
        // Done the first 100.
        n -= 100;
        // First digit is now 'A', 'B' ...
        int firstDigit = 'A' + (n / 36);
        if (firstDigit > 'Z') {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Cannot format number " + n);
        }
        int remainder = n % 36;
        int secondDigit = remainder < 10 ? '0' + remainder : 'A' + (remainder - 10);
        return Character.toString((char) firstDigit) + Character.toString((char) secondDigit);
    }
}

public void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1036; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " = " + strangeNumber(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: nice sollution to , I wanted to use somethink like this, but I like the BigInteger.toString( Character.MAX_RADIX) more.